# How to restrict access on Websockets?

Tags: websocket

I'm trying to figure out how Websockets works. I read some articles, tutorials, etc and I have a pretty basic understanding of how it works, but there is one element that I can't understand how to implement.

My idea is the following : One user will load a "customer" page containing all informations of that customer + a discussion thread. If an other user load that same page, they will be able to discuss in real time and if one user update the data of the customer, the second one will see the update.

The thing that is bugging me, is how can I allow users to access a customer data, but by checking that they can access it (for example, users can access the customer of their group, not all customers)

How can I be sure that the current user will access a customer he has the right (in the websocket)?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of the websocket connection itself as a separate thing. A socket used by a client can subscribe to many different events.

What you're describing is topics. When the websocket connection is established, you send a message using whatever socket framework you're using to subscribe to a topic. For example, it could be a topic called `customer-123`.  (A analogy for a topic, is a chat room)

Your application logic (server side) will verify that the currently logged in user has permission to access customer 123, and if so, permits them to join this topic. If you don't do this, it would be trivial for users to listen to any messages relating to any data.

Whenever a user updates any data that is relevant to customer 123, a message is posted to that topic. And thus, any user who is in that topic will receive the message.

An socket might subscribe to many many topics for each customer they open in your app.  And topics can be combined and managed in groups depending on how you want to send messages.

In a typical large app, it's common to have a websocket subscribe to topics like user-123, team-456 by default so the server can send messages to them individually or to the entire team to which they are a member of.

For example, if a user updates customer-123, I might send a full data object to the customer-123 topic, and if customer 123 belongs to team-456, I would also send a small notification object like 'User 789 has updated customer 123' to the entire team (which is what powers Facebooks feed like system).

As your app grows, you'll use services like notification hubs to manage the fact that there could be thousands of topics each with thousands of subscribers.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is share a session ID and set up authentication token policies between your web application and your socket session.  You could set up your own policy middleware to check the session ID.

You aren't really clear about how you're trying to accomplish this. If you're using express/socket.io, you can use this module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-socket.io-session

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Like any other production application, you need authentication (who is allowed to use the app) and authorization (what functionality can a authenticated user perform).  Authorization (ie, access control - ACL) is probably more precisely what you are looking for.  Your app has to consult an authorization subsystem to see if the current user has access permission to edit/view another user's information.

This is **not** a trivial concern for many applications; security and privacy are important aspects of any web-based (distributed) application.